# Apache Ignite Server to Client connection issues

Tags: server, client, communication, ignite

I have a Apache Ignite server installed on AWS EC2 instance. I'm using s3 bucket for client discovery. I have multiple micro-services deployed in docker container and they are communicating with Ignite server. The problem i'm into is, when my micro-service is registering it self to Ignite server as client, it is working perfectly fine. It is registering with docker containers private IP range, which is not accessible for Ignite server. Now when Ignite server is checking for client heartbeat, it is not able to reach. Can someone please tell what will be the best approach to use ignite with container based architecture.

[image]

output : while server trying to check client status

```
 (wrn) <visor>: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout
 set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of
 network issues [nodeId=8b04f5a6-6b1d-498b-98b2-1044b8c25f3a,
 addrs=[/172.17.0.4:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
```

Comment: It is hard to say what the root cause of the issue. It would be nice to get Ignite configuration for server and client nodes. Perhaps, you need to configure `AddressResolver`. Please take a look at the following links:
 - https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/docker-deployment
- https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/aws-deployment
- http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Connecting-Amazon-cluster-with-client-from-local-tt3453.html#a19965

Comment: Thank you @sk0x50, but this documents does not have much information about the workflow between server and client, when they are deployed in Docker environment.

Comment: In general, your nodes have to be visible in both directions - from client (from you docker container) to server and vice versa.

Comment: @sk0x50 In containerized environment, visibility is the biggest problem. docker containers are running with there own IP range which is not visible or reachable for server. This is where i'm stopped.

Answer (score 0):

1) Let ignite know the address of your EC2 ip

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = //whatever
spi.setLocalAddress( /* ip on ec2 subnet */ );
```

2) Run docker in "host" network mode, as opposed to the default "bridge" mode

These two steps should allow bidirectional TCP handshakes between the members of your Ignite cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can forward host name to the ignite container via a system environment variable in your ignite configuration:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
    <property name="addresses">
        <list>
            <value>#{systemEnvironment['IGNITE_HOST'] ?: '127.0.0.1'}:47500..47509</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

An example of `docker-compose.yml` for 2 communicated ignite services:

```
version: "3"
services:
  ignite:
    image: image_name1
    networks:
      - net
  face:
    image: image_name2
    depends_on:
      - ignite
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
      IGNITE_HOST: 'ignite'
```

The ignite node of 'face' can connect to the another ignite node of 'ignite' using the address `ignite:47500..47509`